# How to output html from content array property?

Tags: php, html, drupal, drupal-7

I'm new to theming and I just inherited this code. I need to control where and how to print #output but it's always showing up at the top of the page, above the HTML tags. I looked at the renderable arrays API but I couldn't find anything specific to my problem.

In mytheme.module:

```
function mytheme_output_block() {
  $content = array(
    '#theme' => 'my_theme',
    '#output' => function_that_returns_JSON();
    ...

function mytheme_hook_theme() {
  return array(
    'my_theme' => array(
      'vars' => array(
      'output' => '',
    ...
```

And in my_theme.tpl.php I tried:

```
<?php print $output; ?>
```

But it gets ignored. How do I control #output so I can style it?

Comment: Are you able to post a more complete code set especially from my_theme.tpl.php?

Comment: Not really :( but the rest shouldn't matter since I'm only concerned with printing $output right now.

Answer (score 0):

not super sure but you might need to call the array element directly.  Something like:

```
$theme = mytheme_hook_theme();
echo $theme['output'];
```

Hope it helps

Comment: I tried <?php $vars = get_defined_vars(); krumo($vars); ?> but $output was empty, even though it's being printed on the page, above the DOCTYPE tag....super confused.

Answer (score 0):

Which Drupal you use? I assume D7.

Take a look at the documentation of hook_theme: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_theme/7.x

1. It's not `vars` - it's `variables`
2. You have missed the `template` key in your implementation

   > **template**: If specified, this theme implementation is a template, and this is the template file without an extension. Do not put .tpl.php on this file; that extension will be added automatically by the default rendering engine (which is PHPTemplate). If 'path', above, is specified, the template should also be in this path.

So what your hook should look like:

```
function mytheme_hook_theme() {
  return array(
    'my_theme' => array(
      'variables' => array(
        'output' => '',
      ),
      'template' => 'my-theme',
    ...
```

Remember to clear the caches afterwards.